# Size of one index of a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, .net

I have defined two three dimensional arrays as:

```
int[, ,] Link_k = new int[length1, length1, length1];
int[][][] Link_k2 = new int[length1][][];
```

where `length1` is variable and could be any integer number.

Now in some point of my code I need to know the size of first index of both arrays. Does anyone know how I could to get?

Comment: @doctor, Ash, Rahul Tripathi, I have changed my question to another one.

Comment: Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GetLength(int dimension)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to determine the size of whatever dimension you want.